# Why won't nothing show. Did I mess up my if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this script that get 2 prices, and then finds the sum of it, and then finds a percentage of the sum depending on what state you choose, and then it adds the percentage. This script worked kind of fine without the if..else statement, but now that I added it, it won't work. Please help. Script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test!!!!!</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Price checker </h2>
<input id = "x" type = "number" placeholder = "Price 1" >
<br><br><br>
<input id = "y" type = "number" placeholder = "Price 2" >
<br><br><br>
<select id="s">
  <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
  <option value="NY">NY</option>
  <option value="PA">PA</option>
  <option value="FL">FL</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<button onclick = "theFunction()">Calculate price</button> 
<p id = "d"></p>
<script>
function theFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("x").value
var y = document.getElementById("y").value
var z = +x + +y
var v = document.getElementById("s").value
var percentToGet;
var percent;
var final;
if v == "NJ" {
var percentToGet = 6.625;


var percent = (percentToGet / 100) * z;
var final = +percent + +z
} else if v == "NY" {
var percentToGet = 4;


var percent = (percentToGet / 100) * z;
var final = +percent + +z
}else if v == "PA" {
var percentToGet = 2;


var percent = (percentToGet / 100) * z;
var final = +percent + +z
} else if v == "FL" {
var percentToGet = 6;


var percent = (percentToGet / 100) * z;
var final = +percent + +z
}





document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = z + " " + final 

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo.  Javascript, like C, requires the expression in `if` statements to be in parentheses:  `if (v == "NH") {`.  If you had checked the console using F12 to bring up the developer tools, you would have seen this.

Comment: Get a decent IDE and linter. It will show you all your syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement in the script tag ,is javascript code which is not having the parentheses.
It will be => `if (v == "NJ")  {  }`

Refer this  MDN Web Docs to learn more [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)